# Using Like operator in parameterized query in SSMS

Tags: azure-sql-database

If I have a parameterized query that looks for a specific piece of information in my SQL Database on Azure, it works great.  For instance, this query gives me the row of data I'm looking for.

```
declare @SearchString nvarchar(250) = 'jflsk@XYZ.com'
select * from ent_entries where uniqueindicator = @SearchString
```

But if I try to use the LIKE operator, I get errors.  When trying this query:

```
declare @SearchString nvarchar(250) = '@XYZ.com'
select * from ent_entries where uniqueindicator like '%' + @SearchString
```

I get the following message:

```
The data types nvarchar(250) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', 
encryption_algorithm_name = 'HIDDENFORPOSTINGONSTACKOVERFLOW', 
column_encryption_key_name = 'HIDDENFORPOSTINGONSTACKOVERFLOW', 
column_encryption_key_database_name = '<HIDDENFORPOSTINGONSTACKOVERFLOW') and 
nvarchar are incompatible in the like operator.
```

From what I've seen on the net this should work, but it just doesn't work for me.  Can anyone see what's wrong?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Denise

Comment: You are likely using alwaysencrypted which does not support arbitrary operations, only equality.  Assuming my guess is correct, you can't do LIKE on the field because the server doesn't have the decryption key - only the client does.

Comment: Yes, I believe it does use alwaysencrypted.  Bummer to hear, but thanks for the info.

Comment: I will comment that we announced such a capability into preview yesterday with SQL Server 2019 CTP 2.0 if you have the right secure enclave support.  You can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That sounds great.  Thanks for sharing.  I look forward to that making it to general availability.  Thanks again.

Comment: Conor, I can't figure out  how to mark your comment as the answer.  Can you tell me how to do that so you can get credit?

Comment: The votes and such are not super-critical to me, but I guess you could vote-up my comment to help others.  I'm just happy to help people use the service.

Comment: I don't see how to vote-up a comment.  Maybe it's an ability I don't have yet or something.  The only thing I see is a flag to report to moderator and I surely don't want to do that.  I do appreciate the help, truly.  :-)